# Passing extra parameters via check_box?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way to pass an id via checkbox?

Let's say we have Model `Record` which stores information. Any user who want to edit a record will need to propose it first for the Admin to approve. The problem is `Record` is linked to multiple `Image` model (with paperclip attachment) so each `Record` `has_many` images. The problem is that I am stuck with how to allow users to propose a deletion of existing photos. I imagine it would be great to store a list of proposed deletion, with image_id and proposal_id to store the deletion waiting for approval but I can't find out a way to program the checkbox.

The checkbox would need to pass in the image_id marked to delete. Is it possible and if so how can I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% @record.images.each do |image| %>
  <%= check_box_tag "image_ids[]", image.id %>
  <%= image_tag image.url %>
<% end %>
```